# Is it possible to get to external sqlite3 file from chrome?

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome-extension

External is that the file lies somewhere on disk out of chrome's directory structure. I was able to create database from content script, but that file was buried deep with chrome dir structure. I need instead to access a hard path like d:\bases\mydb.db3 etc.

I do not how to get to it, is it done from content scripts or background pages ?

Do google extenstions have a hard written security restrictions that don't allow them to reach out of chrome structure into disk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to access the file system like how you stated is through native plugins (NPAPI) mentioned here http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

There are other ways to use file access such as the HTML5 [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). A good tutorial can be read from HTML5 Rocks website http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/filesystem/ That will not read a file that is not managed from the Web.

If you want to bundle a database file to your extension, I recommend dropping SQLite and using compressed JSON. You bundle it up relative to your extension, and fetch it using [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). Chrome has [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html) bundled into the browser, so you can marshal and unmarshal easily.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can it be used to access SQLITE file and perform Queries?